# ValidateAntiForgeryToken attrib ignored in Razor Pages Get-handler

Tags: asp.net-core, csrf, razor-pages

I read that XSRF is "automatically" provided for Razor Pages (Core 2.0) and started wondering how far that went, so I created a small, simple test of an XHR `GET` against a Razor Pages handler. To my surprise, it worked, but upon closer inspection of the headers there wasn't any XSRF going on. Eventually I  concluded "automatic" only applies to form-post scenarios.

I then tried to force an XSRF failure by adding the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute, but it has no effect. Without changing the client code at all, and without adding `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to the cshtml, the method still runs and returns data.

And before anyone says it isn't valid for `HTTP GET` (I've seen answers to older-version MVC questions stating that XSRF *only* applies to form-post), [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery#javascript) states:

> The `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute requires a token for requests to action methods it decorates, including `HTTP GET` requests.

Shouldn't the attribute respond with an error? Do I need some sort of config-magic somewhere to make this work?

This example works by just adding a new "Test" Razor Page to the ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web App template project with the following content.

Test.cshtml.cs:

```
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public void OnGet() { }

    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult OnGetMySecretData() => 
        new JsonResult("requested super-secret data");
}
```

Test.cshtml:

```
@page
@model Site.Pages.TestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<script>
    function test() {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", location.origin + "/Test?handler=mysecretdata");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        xhr.onreadystatechange = progress;
        xhr.onerror = notOk;
        xhr.send()
    }

    function progress() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                document.querySelector("#message").textContent = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                notOk();
            }
        }
    }

    function notOk() {
        document.querySelector("#message").textContent = "ERROR " + xhr.responseText + " (" + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText + ")";
    }
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="test()" value="Test" />
<br />
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, got sidetracked on another issue and haven't circled back yet.

Comment: check this maybe helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353875/manual-anti-forgery-token-creation-and-validation-in-asp-net-5